# jboss-as-maven-plugin - add mail session resource

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm trying to find a way to add a mail session resource to my jboss-as-maven-plugin but I'm not really making a lot of progress.. Anyone has got some tutorial or something? I can't find any..

This is the complete plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-datasource</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=java:jboss/datasources/eCadWSDS</address>
                        <resource>
                            <enable-resource>true</enable-resource>
                            <properties>
                                <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/eCadWSDS</jndi-name>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                                <driver-class>org.h2.Driver</driver-class>
                                <driver-name>h2</driver-name>
                            </properties>
                        </resource>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-mail-session</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <address>subsystem=mail-session, mail-session=java:jboss/mail/eCad</address>
                        <resource>
                            <enable-resource>true</enable-resource>
                            <properties>
                                <jndi-name>java:jboss/mail/eCad</jndi-name>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <socket-binding>mail-smtp</socket-binding>
                            </properties>
                        </resource>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> 
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-to-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>                    
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is what I would like to configurate in this plugin:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
   <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/eCad">
     <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
   </mail-session>
</subsystem>

<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
  <remote-destination host="filenetsupport" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:add-resource (add-mail-session) on project ecad-application-ws-ear: Could not execute goal add-resource. Reason: Operation failed: "JBAS014739: No handler for read-resource at address [(\"subsystem\" => \"mail-session\")]" -> [Help 1]
```

So I stil have to add the "outbound-socket-binding" and link that binding to the mail session.. But I don't have a clue on how to do that.

I've tried adding the mail session with a CLI command since I know how to do that.. But I started to try to add the datasource first. So i've added the following execution:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>execute-commands</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <execute-commands>
                            <commands>

                                <command>/subsystem=datasources/data-source="java:jboss/datasources/eCadWSDS":add(jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/eCadWSDS", driver-name="h2", connection-url="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")</command>
                            </commands>
                        </execute-commands> 
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

and I've removed the add-resource execution for the datasource just for testing purposes. But it seems that the datasource is never added. Although that I'm getting an exception if I write something wrong in the command.. so it IS executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're configuration is slightly off. The subsystem name is `mail` not `mail-session` and there needs to be no spaces in the address.

Also there is no `enable` attribute. Try the following:

```xml
<configuration>
    <address>subsystem=mail,mail-session=java:jboss/mail/eCad</address>
    <resource>
        <properties>
            <jndi-name>java:jboss/mail/eCad</jndi-name>
            <socket-binding>mail-smtp</socket-binding>
        </properties>
    </resource>
</configuration>
```